# wind versus compressed air

Tags: energy-conservation

What would the calculation look like when computing the wind pressure of a moving vehilce versus compressed air pressure pushing against the the moving vehicle, how much compressed air pressure would be needed to combat the wind of the moving vehicle.?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking what is the air pressure caused by a vehicle moving?

It's a little complicated for a real vehicle with aerodynamics and air moving around it - but if you imagine a simple shaped object the force is

[image: can somebody Tex this?]

Which says that the force from the air is 1/2 * density of air * velocity squared * drag coeeficent * area

But since pressure is force / area we can drop the area bit and have the pressure of air just depends on the speed (v^2) and the shape Cd

You can look up Cd for different shapes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation.  But it's generally between 1 for a flat plate and 0.05 for a very streamlined teardrop.